# Conditional operator: conversion from 'int ' to 'unsigned char ', possible loss of data

Tags: c++, conditional-operator

I have the following C code:

```
a = (b == B1) ? A1 : A2;
```

`a`, `b`, `A1`, `A2` and `B1` are all of type `unsigned char`. `A1`, `A2` and `B1` are all constants.

When compiling under VC++ I see the following warning:

```
warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'int ' to 'unsigned char ', possible loss of data
```

I don't understand this warning - none of the variables are of type `int`. Presumably some kind of implicit conversion is happening, but why?

Strangely, the following code (which is functionally identical) compiles with no warnings:

```
if (b == B1) {
  a = A1;
} else {
  a = A2;
}
```

So far as I'm aware, the two code extracts should be identical.

Comment: With `#define A1 42`, the type of `A1` is `int`, not `unsigned char`. Just saying. Anyway ... I'm inclined to think you are compiling with a C++ compiler and the question is mis-tagged.

Comment: @pmg - the constants are #defined with casts - see my comment on Paulo's answer below. I don't know whether MS VC++ does anything different when compiling C rather than C++ code, so I don't know if that makes a difference or not.

Comment: Well then, your compiler is trying to be more helpful than it really needs to :) The warning about assigning an `int` to an `unsigned char` isn't required by C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C language arithmetic arguments of ternary `?:` operator are subjected to usual arithmetic conversions, i.e. they are promoted to `int` before any further computations are performed. It doesn't really matter whether they are constants or not. What matters is that they have type `unsigned char` (as you said) and `unsigned char` under `?:` is always promoted first. Basically, C language never performs any computations in types smaller than `int`. Everything smaller is converted to `int` first.

This is what happens in your case as well. Basically, your

```
a = (b == B1) ? A1 : A2;
```

is interpreted by C language as

```
a = ((int) b == (int) B1) ? (int) A1 : (int) A2;
```

and this is why you get the warning. Again, the fact that `A1` and `A2` are constants plays no role whatsoever.

The

```
a = A1;
```

does not subject the right-hand side to integral promotion, which is why there's no warning here. Moreover, in this trivial case (direct assignment) even if `A1` was explicitly declared as an `int` constant, most compilers would not issue a warning if they could see that the constant is in range of the target type `unsigned char`. The case with `?:` is more complicated, so the compilers might revert to the generic behavior and issue a warning.

Comment: Thanks - I've now found the relevant part of the C99 standard that details this behaviour. 6.5.15, p5: "If both the second and third operands have arithmetic type, the result type that would be determined by the usual arithmetic conversions, were they applied to those two operands, is the type of the result."

Answer (score 3):

Although functionally the same, both codes are not quite equals.

You see, when you use a ternary operator, that is the `condition ? true_value : false_value`, the compiler tries to infer between the values the best possible type.

Because A1 and A2 are constant (as you state in the O.P.) the compiler replaces their position by their actual values, ignoring completely the data type, rendering both as integers.

Hence the need to cast the result, as such:

```
a = (unsigned char)((b == B1) ? A1 : A2);
```

Comment: That makes sense. Slightly odd/irritating because the constants are #defined explicitly with a cast (e.g. `#define A1 ((unsigned char)0x01))` - but I guess the compiler is still free to just look at the values, as you suggest..

Comment: Well, this answer is incorrect. Firstly, the OP explicitly stated that the constants have `unsigned char` type, i.e. they are declared with a cast. The compiler does not ignore the type, but rather *promotes* the operands to the larger type.

Answer (score 2):

```
  a = (unsigned char)((b == B1) ? A1 : A2);
```

I believe this is because there is no rvalues in the sub statements -- they get auto converted to int in the lexer.  The code above should solve the warning message and have no effect on the resulting code.